# If I call Quantile multiple times in a loop can I save to DataFrame?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe z of sql statments 
ie select age from table where state='fl',
   select age from table where state='ny', etc

I then loop thru the dataframe to run each query then run the output thru
the Quantile fct to get Percentiles for each query which I write to a file

Is there a way to save the Quantile output to a dataframe ???

Thanks

```
for (x in z) {
     dflist <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, x)

     # Loop thru dataframe dflist and run percentile and write to file
     lapply(dflist, function(df) {

     write.table(matrix(quantile(dflist$los, c(0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90))[c(1,2,3,4,5)], nrow=1),file="/foo.txt", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append = TRUE)
     NULL
     })



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. The easy way would be to create a new `lapply` function to store it directly but I ll show you a way to do it in your current `lapply` function (to avoid looping twice):

**Data**

```
a <- runif(50)
b <- runif(50)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

**Solution**

```
#initiate a list
mylist <- list()

lapply(df, function(x) {
  #save quantile in the list on each loop
  #notice the <<- operator below that will modify the list in the global environment
  mylist[[length(mylist)+1]] <<- quantile(x, c(0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90))

  #also do your write.table function below as you did
  write.table(matrix(quantile(dflist$los, c(0.10, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90))[c(1,2,3,4,5)], nrow=1),file="/foo.txt", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append = TRUE)
})
```

And it will work doing the following:

```
df2 <- data.frame(mylist)
colnames(df2) <- c('a','b')

> df2
            a         b
10% 0.1143816 0.0386159
25% 0.2301640 0.2265687
50% 0.4753750 0.4696076
75% 0.7633871 0.6843929
90% 0.9312094 0.8813031
```

And this way it works with only one `lapply` and you save the quantiles as well in a data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply that works great. One followup question - is there a way to get the data from the LIST in rows where each row is that data from each call to quantile  ie like the output file if formatted ???  Thanks again

Comment: Happy to have helped :). Using the `t()` function on a data.frame, it will be transposed (but some fixing of names might be required). Also, `t()` coerces a data.frame to matrix which means you need to use `as.data.frame` again to convert it back to a data.frame